# glRotatef works on multiple objects

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Basicly I want to open a Door and I thought of using glRotatef.
My Problem is that it is affecting every object which is drawn after it.
Does anyone know how to stop that ?

Door.class

```
    public static void draw(Texture door) {  

    door.bind();
    if(Door_Test.state == "out" && d != 90){
        glRotatef(i, 0, 1, 0);
        i+=5;
    }
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(-2,3, -15);
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(-2,-3, -15);
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(2,-3, -15);
        glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(2,3, -15);
    glEnd();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate, it rotates the entire scene. So to rotate a single object, you rotate the entire scene, draw your object, then rotate your screen back.

```
glRotatef(i, 0, 1, 0);

// Draw object.

glRotatef(-i, 0, 1, 0);
```

As [Reto Koradi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3530129/reto-koradi) pointed out, if you continually do this you might have floating point rounding errors that accumulate over time. [HolyBlackCat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944030/2197700) offers a better solution.

Comment: Thx it works :D
The only thing left is it's rotating around the false axis ^^

Comment: Note that if you do this repeatedly, it can still change your transformation over time due to rounding errors. The approach in the other answer, using `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`, is better IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Common way to do it:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(/*...*/);
// Drawing commands here
glPopMatrix();
```